# VBA/Excel - Subrotinas param enquanto estou digitando

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Estou trabalhando em uma planilha em que o usuário tem que digitar um dado texto em uma célula em um certo tempo. Quero colocar um contador regressivo lado, para ele ir verificando quanto tempo ainda falta. Porém, quando eu começo a digitar na célula, a função do cronômetro para de funcionar (para de contar), e volta somente após eu dar Enter. Sou novo em VBA, talvez seja alguma configuração, ou onde estou rodando as subrotinas, e eu não saiba ainda.

As rotinas do contador regressivo são estas:

```
Private Sub Iniciar_crono()
    starttimer
End Sub

Sub starttimer()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "nexttick"
End Sub

Sub nexttick()
    If Plan3.Range("E3") = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Plan3.Range("E3").Value = Plan3.Range("E3").Value - TimeValue("00:00:01")

    If Plan3.Range("E3").Value <= TimeValue("00:00:10") Then
        Plan2.Shapes("TextBox 1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Else
        Plan2.Shapes("TextBox 1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    End If

    starttimer

End Sub


Private Sub Parar_crono()
    stoptimer
End Sub

Sub stoptimer()
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "nexttick", , False
End Sub
```

Para orientação:
- Um botão para iniciar o contador chama a Iniciar_crono()
- Um botão para pará-lo chama a Parar_crono()
- É tudo hoje rodado no Módulo 1

Comment: Como o colega @cantoni já bem colocou na resposta dele, o Excel bloqueia a execução do timer enquanto se está no modo de edição. Fui dar uma olhada na Internet pra ver se seria possível você fazer isso com as [funções de timer nativas do Windows](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/OnTime.aspx). E é, porque diferentemente das do VBA, elas não são bloqueadas. Só que, mesmo assim, você vai incorrer em outro problema: o Excel provavelmente vai travar se você tentar alterar um valor de célula enquanto ele estiver no modo de edição. :/

Comment: Ok, já entendi o que estou fazendo de errado. Vou tentar outros meios. Uma opção que pensei é preencher uma Caixa de Texto flutuante, ao invés de uma célula. Fiz um teste, e ele não faz parar a execução de código VBA. Não queria muito fazer fora do Excel, pois estou fazendo esse aplicativo principalmente para aprender VBA, então, quanto maior o desafio melhor! =)

Comment: Se é só pra aprender, então você já aprendeu algo. ;) Mas, uma alternativa pra fazer o que você quer é usar um campo de texto em um *formulário de usuário* (mais informações aqui: http://www.macoratti.net/12/12/vba_lgn1.htm). Assim, você tem total controle sobre o que o usuário pode digitar, ou quanto tempo ele vai levar pra isso. E, pode transferir os dados de lá para as células da planilha (que podem estar bloqueadas para edição).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O cronometro para de contar, pois no momento que você está digitando em uma célula, o Excel interrompe qualquer execução de código VBA. Desconheço uma maneira de modificar esse comportamento, faz parte do design do Excel e deve ter uma boa razão para tal.

Enfim, da maneira que está exposto o problema, não será possível resolvê-lo devido ao design do Excel, como dito acima.

Uma possível solução é fazer o timer fora do Excel. Implementado o mesmo em .NET, por exmeplo. Assim, você pode instanciar a DLL a partir do Excel e fazer um botão (no Excel) para chamar a rotina de iniciar e parar o cronometro.

Comment: Você tem razão sobre o Excel bloquear o timer temporariamente enquanto no modo de edição. Mas não me parece que o código do AP está errado. Ele só está re-agendando a chamada do timer para um segundo a frente novamente. Não há empilhamento de chamadas ai, e por isso não vai ocorrer stackoverflow. :)

Comment: É verdade @LuizVieira, o código da maneira que está me levou a uma interpretação errada. Vou retirar essa parte da resposta. Obrigado!